# it is possible to cache tensorflow models in browser, or monitor downloading progress?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am using tensorflow.js in the browser (with the posenet models). I notice that the library downloads a large amount of files when it is initialized. I wonder if there is some way change the load preferences, by example to load them from local indexedDB, or at least it there is a way to use a callback function or something in order to show progress of download to the user? 
right now, in slow networks it took many minutes and even displaying a spinning loader users tends to believe the page is frozen, closing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Which files is the browser downloading? Could it be that more than just the model and the weights is being downloaded?)*

**Caching:**

The model is usually cached automatically. If the resource has not changed (HTTP status 304) the cached model will be used.

However the first time a client connects to the application it has to download everything.

To reduce waiting time you can try the following ideas:

1. Reduce the size by adjusting the [quantization bytes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet#config-params-in-posenetload) in the model.
2. Change the model you are using.
3. Change the batch size.

You can use 2 and 3 only if you are using your retrained model.

---

**Progress callback:**

If you are using one of the tfjs [loading functions](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#Models-Loading) you can specify a configuration object with a `onProgress` function:

```js
const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(modelUrl, {onProgress: p => console.log(p)})
```

Since you are using posenet I imagine you are using the built-in loading function:

```js
async function load(config: ModelConfig);
```

Unfortunately this function is a wrapper for `tf.loadGraphModel(url)` so it does not pass the extra options (including `onProgress`) to the `loadGraphModel` function.

What you could do is rewrite the [posenet loading function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/blob/015ccaf2506a7e09ea23dc3b051552eb72e558c0/posenet/src/posenet_model.ts#L440) to call `tf.loadGraphModel()` with the `onProgress` callback.

Comment: thank you for your reply, the tip about rewriting posenet loading function is the path I was trying to discover!